# Блокировка регуляторов звука

Tags: c++, linux, c, alsa

Можно ли каким либо способом программно заблокировать изменение уровня звука в системе?

Как получить и установить с помощью ALSA я знаю, а вот как предотвратить изменение уровня во время работы моего ПО - пока для меня загадка....

И можно ли это сделать вообще?

Comment: даже если бы это было возможно технически, этого ни в коем случае нельзя делать: писателей подобного вредительства бьют канделябрами по голове.

Comment: В мире софта, а тем более с открытыми исходниками, можно всё!

Comment: А вообще в поиске готовых решений я бы посмотрел на возможные установки микшера. Так же в ALSA можно создавать софтверный микшер.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Вы через чур категоричны! Если это необходимо для дела - а это именно так - почему нет?

Comment: нашел функцию [snd_ctl_elem_lock](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___control.html#ga1fba1f7e08ab11505a617af5d54f4580) - как я понял что -то из нужной области

где б еще примерчик использования найти?